# WP CLI can't delete plugin related table

Tags: wp-query, wp-cli, phpmyadmin, wp-load.php, wp-reset-postdata

I have installed a plugin following `wp plugin install ...` CLI command and then activate through CLI command its working properly. But problem is that when I deactivate then delete the plugin the table which is related to this plugin is still in my database. Is there any way to delete the unused unnecessary tables from wp database?

Answer (score 4):

That is the responsibility of the author of the plugin. Amazingly some authors believe that it is wrong to delete information from the DB, which I personally find unbelievable, but I guess there are all kinds of users that do not think or backup before they delete things, and they were crying for such functionality (i.e., for plugins to not delete DB on plugin delete).

Comment: as a note: some things are really not trivial to delete, as they might get used in other contexts as well. Creating a DB structure that is easy to delete is not always a simple task.

Comment: Also, plugins get deactivated and deleted for all kinds of reasons. There seems to be an emerging standard to provide an option (that is not selected by default!) to remove all database data connected to the plugin on deactivation. I like this solution a lot and encourage plugin developers to go this route.

Comment: it means that if someone didn't pay attentention he is left with garbage in the DB that can not be deleted. Not a huge problem if it is in separate tables, but can lead to performance degradation if its options.

Answer (score 1):

wp-cli does not have a feature in it that enables you to delete a specific table; you can only delete the entire database.

You'll have to manually delete the table through SQL.